# Combine left sides from nested disjunction result type

Tags: scala, scalaz

If I have a type `\/[Errs, \/[Errs, Boolean]]` and want to combine two lefts (two `Errs`) what's the best way to make it `\/[Errs,Boolean]` where new `Errs` will be appending two `Errs` from two `lefts` from the earlier type. `Errs` is nothing but a `case class`

```
case class Errs(errors: List[Err])
```

And `Err` is

```
 case class Err(exceptionMessage: String, customMessage: String, statusCode: Int, extraInfo: Option[String] = None)
```

I am trying to convert `type1 = \/[Errs, \/[Errs,Boolean]]` to `type2 = \/[Errs,Boolean]` where `Errs` in `type2` should be  "merged" `Errs` (without losing any `left` info from combining two disjunctions.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. You want a `\/[Errs, \/[Errs, Boolean]] => \/[Errs, \/[Errs, Boolean]] => \/[Errs, Boolean]`?

Comment: @TravisBrown : Hi Travis, That's true. I updated question adding more clarity. let me know if I should add an example if still not clear? was thinking about `EitherT` but not sure if that's a right way here? any idea?

Comment: Thanks!—I still don't see how merging can be an issue, though? Does `t1.flatMap(identity)` work?

Comment: @TravisBrown : yeah. t1.flatMap(identity) does work. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness: because this is a disjunction, you'll never have to worry about "merging" errors—either the whole thing is an `Errs` on the left side, or it's a right with an `Errs` on the left. It can't be both at the same time.

If you want to collapse the two levels, `t1.flatMap(identity)` will turn `Errs \/ (Errs \/ Boolean)` into a plain old `Errs \/ Boolean`.